# Android Button Programmaticallly

Tags: android, layout, button

I have following structure in XML.

```
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tagsTable"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dip" android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/btn_white_add_9"
                        android:text="Tag" android:layout_margin="2px"></Button>
                    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/btn_white_add_9"
                        android:text="Tag" android:layout_margin="2px"></Button>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/btn_white_add_9"
                        android:text="Tag" android:layout_margin="2px"></Button>
                    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/btn_white_add_9"
                        android:text="Tag" android:layout_margin="2px"></Button>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/btn_white_add_9"
                        android:text="This Tag is very big that it has full width :)" android:layout_margin="2px"
                        android:paddingLeft="5px" android:paddingRight="25px"></Button>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Above layout results into...

[image]

But when the same thing I do with that code.

```
        LinearLayout tagsTable = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tagsTable);
        tagsTable.removeAllViews();

        LinearLayout currentRow = new LinearLayout(this);
        MarginLayoutParams params = new MarginLayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setTag(Id);
        button.setText(Name);
        button.setTextColor(0xFF736F6E);
        button.setPadding(10, 0, 30, 0);
        button.setOnTouchListener(new TagTouchListener());

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);
        button.setLayoutParams(params);

        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_blue_add_9);

        currentRow.addView(button);
        tagsTable.addView(currentRow);
```

[image]

The prominent problems are of vertical spacing and size of the button which is changed in both scenarios. The XML way is doing it perfect. What I am doing wrong in code?

Comment: Why not just use XML and if you need to determine the rows at row time, just keep loading the XML over and over?

Comment: Can't. The problem won't be solved.

Answer (score 2):

In xml you have :

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

So in java you could try :

```
currentRow.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: I am using MarginLayoutParams right now. That shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: In your code you write :         MarginLayoutParams params = new MarginLayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
But you never used it So your currentRow is not set to have its width equals to fill_parent. You have to do somewhere a : currentRow;setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: OK I tried it and this is there now but still the same effect. It feels like vertical align needs to be set. I noticed one other thing, the setPadding doesn't work on the button either. why is that the behaviour?

Comment: is layout_weight auto set in XML layout?